# ruby reduce duplication

Tags: ruby

```
class Car
    attr_accessor :door, :window, :engine, :wheel, :mirror, :seat...
end

my_car = Car.new
my_car.door, my_car.window, my_car.engine, my_car.wheel = "door", "window", "engine", "wheel"
```

I don't want to repeatedly type `my_car`. I know I can define `initialize(door, window, engine, wheel)`, but is there other way to do that? Something like

```
my_car.METHOD do
    door, window, engine, wheel = "door", "window", "engine", "wheel"
end
```

Comment: What's the problem with defining `initialize()`? Why are you trying to initialize this object from outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the question part of *'is there are any other way':*

This form

```
my_car.METHOD do
  door, window, engine, wheel = "door", "window", "engine", "wheel"
end
```

is similar to the **instance_eval** which evaluates block in the context of an object:

```
my_car.instance_eval do
  @door = "door"
  @window = "window"
end
```

P.S. Not arguing whether it's the best way, though :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the constructor:

```
class Car
  attr_accessor :door, :window, :engine, :wheel, :mirror

  def initialize(opts={})
     opts.each {|k,v| self.send("#{k}=", v)}
  end
end
```

Then you can provide all the options at object creation time:

```
my_car = Car.new(:door => "4dr", :engine => "2.4L")

p my_car
#<Car:0x8a585f4 @door="4dr", @engine="2.4L">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%w(door window) |f|
    my_car.send(f + "=", "some string, possibly f itself like the next line")
    my_car.send(f + "=", f)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe facets can help you:
[Module.assign](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Kernel.html#method-i-assign)

Then this will be:

```
my_car.assign( :door => "door", :window => "window" .... )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually define a yield initialize:

```
def initialize(&block)
  instance_eval(&block)
end
```

Then

```
my_car = Car.new do
  @door = "door"
  @window = "window"
  #...
end
```

The fact you have to use @attr, is because that statement like "var = value" will assume you set a new local variant.